# Python import fails (in slurm environment)

Tags: python, python-2.7, cluster-computing, python-import, slurm

Let's assume the file structure (simplified) looks like this:

```
> some_script.py
> +extra_directory/
> ++ __init__.py
> ++ extra_script.py
```

In my python file `some_script.py` I have some import which looks like this:

```
from extra_directory.extra_script import extra_class
```

This runs fine on my desktop.

However, when I run this on the cluster in a [Slurm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slurm_Workload_Manager) environment I always get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/work/var/slurmd/state.node253.d/job17281/slurm_script", line 2, in
>   
>       from distributions.convert_to_distribution import DistributionConverter as DC ImportError: No module named
>   distributions.convert_to_distribution

Where the distributions stuff is the real name of the extra_directory example.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

To clarify my situation: I actually have `__init__.py` scripts in every directory (just forget to mention it here). However, the imports are **still failing**.

My current **workaround** is to add the absolute path in my scripts:

```
sys.path.append("/absolute/path/to/extra_directory")
```

Comment: are you sure your script starts in the directory you assume it is starting? What does the script header look like?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an empty file `__init__.py`inside `extra_directory` so that Python will treat `extra_directory` as a Python package.

According to [Modules - Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html):

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the **all** variable, described later.

The file structure should be like this:

```
> some_script.py
> extra_directory/
>     __init__.py
>     extra_script.py
```

There should be a class named `extra_class` inside `extra_script.py`.

```
class extra_script(object):
    pass
```

Then you can import it successfully from `some_script.py`:

```
from extra_directory.extra_script import extra_class
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess someone always forget the `__init__.py`. However, I have init's in every directory but the imports fail nevertheless. At the moment my workaround is to include the absolute path to my extra directory: `sys.path.append("/absolute/path/to/extra_directory")`